# Kubernetes - Find per core statistics for the pod

Tags: linux, kubernetes, cpu-usage, prometheus

I would want to find the per core usage statistics for my Kubernetes pod.

In my Linux host/in the Kubernetes node, I use `mpstat` to find the statistics like below.

[image]

In my case, I assign 2.5 CPUs to the Kubernetes container and when I try the same `mpstat` command from inside the container, I get the same details as above showing all the host CPUs(16 in my case)

I used `kubectl top` command, but it just shows the overall CPU used by the pod but not per CPU statistics assigned to the container.

Prometheus' `container_cpu_usage_seconds_total` gives a similar overall details but not individual CPU details.

How do I get `mpstat` like statistics, like shown above, for the Kubernetes pod.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is crossposted: https://superuser.com/questions/1824796/how-to-get-per-core-statistics-for-the-kubernetes-pod-that-is-displayed-like-mp

Comment: If the detailed response I have drafted  helped you in clarifying the issue, I request you to give feedback as stated [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

A **[kubectl top](https://signoz.io/blog/kubectl-top/)**  is a command used to list all the running nodes and pods along with their resource utilization. It provides you a snapshot of resource utilization metrics like CPU, memory, and storage on each running node.

> Each node in Kubernetes comes with **cAdvisor**, it is a container monitoring tool that provides detailed information about resource usage, including CPU and memory. kubectl command gets resource utilization metrics from cAdvisor via the metrics-server. This command requires **Metrics Server** to be correctly configured and working on the server.

Metrics Server is a component that exposes resource usage metrics for Kubernetes objects, including pods. Try installing a [metrics server](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/) or you can use [k9](https://github.com/derailed/k9s) which is an easy way to check all your resources cpu and memory usage.

You can get memory and cpu usage of pod from cgroup without installing metrics server or any third party tool by running below commands :

1.Navigate to pod's exec mode by running `kubectl exec -it pod\_name -n namespace -- /bin/bash`

2.For CPU usage run `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpuacct.usage`

3.For memory usage run `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage\_in\_bytes`

**Note** : Add the resources section (requests and limits) to deployment so that it can calculate the usage based on cgroup and container will respect the limits set on pod level and this usage is in bytes which can vary upon pod usage and these values change frequently.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpuacct.usage` just gives me the overall usage not individual core usage. I need to know what percent of each core allocated to the pod is spent being idle, on application usage etc.,

Comment: Can you try installing a metrics server or you can use k9 which is an easy way to check all your resources cpu and memory usage. You can also refer to this [Iink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895929/) for more information.

Comment: I have the metrics server but it does not have any metric related to % cpu usage of each core.

Comment: The metrics server provides the kubernetes cluster with a lightweight and highly scalable solution for tracking  resource usage, including CPU and memory usage of pods. However, Kubernetes metric server does not have a built-in metric for per core usage. To obtain that you have to consider using other monitoring tools  eg. Prometheus, Grafana or custom metrics.